# How to find specific text in a text file, and append it to the filename?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, mv

I have a collection of plain text files which are named as `yymmdd_nnnnnnnnnn.txt`, which I want to append another number sequence to the filenames, so that they each become named as `yymmdd_nnnnnnnnnn_iiiiiiiii.txt` instead, where the `iiiiiiiii` is taken from the one line in each file which contains the text "`GST: 123456789`⏎" (or similar) at the end of the line. While I am sure that there will only be one such matching line within each file, I don't know exactly which line it will be on.

I need an elegant one-liner solution that I can run over the collection of files in a folder, from a bash script file, to rename each file in the collection by appending the specific GST number for each filename, as found within the files themselves.

Before even getting to the renaming stage, I have encountered a problem with this. Here is what I tried, which didn't work...

```bash
# awk '/\d+$/' | grep -E 'GST: ' 150101_2224567890.txt
```

The `grep` command alone works perfectly to find the relevant line within the file, but the `awk` doesn't return just the final digits group. It fails with the error "warning: regexp escape sequence \d is not a known regexp operator". I had assumed that this regex should return any number of digits which are at the end of the line. The text file in question contains a line which ends with "`GST: 112060340`⏎". Can someone please show me how to make this work, and maybe also to help with the appropriate coding to move the collection of files to the new filenames? Thanks.

---

Thanks to a comment from @Renaud, I now have the following code working to obtain just the GST registration number from within a text file, which puts me a step closer towards a workable solution.

```bash
awk '/GST: / {printf $NF}' 150101_2224567890.txt
```

I still need to loop this over the collection instead of just specifying one filename. I also need to be able to use the output from @Renaud's contribution, to rename the files. I'm getting closer to a working solution, thanks!

Comment: Your command cannot work: the `awk` part has no input to process and it sends its output to a command (`grep -E 'GST: ' 150101_2224567890.txt`) that takes no input. You should consider reading the bash manual to better understand how pipes work and in what direction data flows. Anyway, using `awk` **and** `grep` is frequently wrong. Use one or the other, not both. Try maybe `awk '/^GST: / {printf $NF}' 150101_2224567890.txt` (if `GST` is at the beginning of the line and what you search for is the last word of the same line).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Renaud. So, I got the inputs and outputs back to font then, huh? Reversing them didn't make a difference either. I tried your solution above, but it didn't return anything at all.

Also, as I mentioned in the OP, the text "`GST: 112060340`⏎" is at the end of the line, not the beginning.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the `^` start of line character from your solution here, @Renaud, and this part now works perfectly for me, thanks for that. Any idea how to now use this result in a piped command which will rename the file, as mentioned in the OP?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @M. I tried your code and it came back with an error, "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'".

Comment: Hmm, I tried it again just now, @M., and it did give an output containing the mv command, but I would then have to copy that output and execute it manually. I was hoping to have this all done in a single step.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that @M., you had mentioned that previously, but I missed that part. It works great now. If you want to write that up as a solution, I will accept it.

Comment: What is an _one-liner_ exactly? You can put as many statements as you like into a single line. Virtually every bash program can become an one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
for f in *_*.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.txt}_$(sed '/.*GST: /!d; s///; q' "$f").txt"; done
```

Drop the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does in fact solve my problem perfectly. I know that I need to learn more about using tools like `awk`, `grep`, `sed` etc. But for now I just needed a quick and dirty solution to a specific problem, and this really helped me a lot. I will come back at some time and learn more about the solutions offered here, so that I actually understand them. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk '$1=="GST:" {fn=FILENAME; sub(/\.txt$/, "", fn); print "mv", FILENAME, fn "_" $2 ".txt"; nextfile}' *_*.txt | sh
```

To make it more readable:

```bash
awk '$1 == "GST:" {
   fn = FILENAME
   sub(/\.txt$/, "", fn)
   print "mv", FILENAME, fn "_" $2 ".txt"
   nextfile
}' *_*.txt | sh
```

Remove `| sh` from above to see all `mv` commands together.

Comment: Thanks for this, @anubhava. However, as I mentioned in the OP, "I need an elegant one-liner solution...". Can I just remove the linefeeds from your code here to have it all on one line?

Comment: I tested it as one liner only: `awk '$1=="GST:" {fn=FILENAME; sub(/\.txt$/, "", fn); print "mv", FILENAME, fn "_" $2 ".txt"; nextfile}' *_*.txt | sh` but showed it with line breaks it to make it more readable.

Comment: You can replace the newlines between statements with semicolons. Requiring a one-liner is often a misdirected endeavor, though. If you need to reuse the code, put it in a function or a script.

Comment: Interesting. I have now tried both of your samples here, @anubhava, and I can not get either of them to work, with or without the linefeed breaks.

Comment: What output did you get with `| sh` removed? That command worked pretty well for me using gnu and non-gnu awk

Answer (score 1):

As you are sure there is only one matching line, you can try:

```bash
$ n=$(awk '/GST:/ {print $NF}' 150101_2224567890.txt)
$ mv 150101_2224567890.txt "150101_2224567890_$n.txt"
```

Or, for all `.txt` files:

```bash
for f in *.txt; do
  n=$(awk '/GST:/ {print $NF}' "$f")
  if [[ -z "$n" ]]; then
    printf '%s: GST not found\n' "$f"
    continue
  fi
  mv "$f" "$f{%.txt}_$n.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much for persisting with this, @Renaud. You were right in your initial assumption, that I am a complete n00b at this, and I should RTFM! Haha. I just needed a quick black box solution that I can plug in as a one-liner, and M. Nejat Aydin came the closest to providing such a solution. I assume yours would work by again replacing the linefeeds for semicolons, right?

Answer (score 0):

Another one-line solution to consider, although perhaps not so elegant.

```
for original_filename in *_*.txt; do \
new_filename=${original_filename%'.txt'}_$(
    grep -E 'GST: ' "$original_filename" | \
    sed -E 's/.*GST//g; s/[^0-9]//g' 
    )'.txt' && \
mv "$original_filename" "$new_filename"; \
done
```

Output:

```
150101_2224567890_123456789.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a multi line script:-

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.txt; do
prefix=$(echo "${f}" | sed s'@\.txt@@')
cp "${f}" f1
sed -i s'@GST@%GST@' "./f1"
cat "./f1" | tr '%' '\n' > f2
number=$(cat "./f2" | sed -n '/GST/'p | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ')
newname="${prefix}_${number}.txt"
mv -v "${f}" "${newname}"
rm -v "./f1"
rm -v "./f2"
done
```

In general, if you want to make your files easy to work with, then leave as many potential places for them to be split with newlines as possible.  It is ***much*** easier to alter files by simply being able to put what you want to delete or print on its' own line, than it is to search for things horizontally with regular expressions.